# unable to change python tab width in vim

Tags: python, vim

I am unable to set a custom tab width in my ~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim file.

In that file I have the commands:

```
echo "HERE in python.vim"
setlocal smarttab
setlocal expandtab
setlocal shiftwidth=2
setlocal tabstop=2
setlocal softtabstop=2
```

I see the `echo` message when I edit a `.py` file so I know this file is getting run.

However, using the TAB key indents by 4 spaces, not 2 on `.py` files.

If after loading a `.py` file I use:

```
:source ~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim
```

the tab stops are set to 2 spaces.

It seems the installed python mode is overriding my settings.

Is there a way to run commands after an ftplugin file is run?

I know the PEP-recommended tab width is 4.

Comment: Can you try putting the plugin file in 'after' directory, or try loading that setting through autocommand in .vimrc like :au BufEnter *.py setlocal tabstop=2

Comment: The :au approach seems to work. Commands placed in ~/.vim/after/python.vim don't seem to get run.

Comment: Move that file to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`.